# Xamarin.Android : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied

Tags: xamarin.android

I am targeting Android API 30. My app was storing log file and taking database backup in location "/storage/emulated/0/SpecialDir/". Now I am facing access denied issue while my app was workinng fine previously.
I got an overview about scoped storage and came to know that we have some managed locaitons where we can store our data accordingly. i.e Audio, Video, Images, and Download

- My question is What is the solution for existing apps that was previously saving files on "/storage/emulated/0/SpecialDir/".

Can anyone please guide me what should i do.

```js
string dir = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString(), "LogFolder");
if (Directory.Exists(dir))
{
    return Path.Combine(dir, "MyLogFile.txt");
}
try
{
   string newDirectory = Directory.CreateDirectory(dir).FullName;
   path = Path.Combine(newDirectory, "MyLogFile.txt");
   System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "This is some testing log.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   string msg = ex.Message;
}
```

The above code is used to make 'LogFolder' if not exist and 'MyLogFile' as well. What changes do i needed to make it compatiable to Android 10. Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

In Android `10`, Google has introduced a new feature for external Storage. Its name is `Scoped Storage`. Google officially translates it as partitioned Storage, or `Scoped Storage`.The intent is to limit what programs can do with public directories in external storage. Partitioned storage has no effect on either the `internal storage private directory` or the `external storage private directory`.In short, in Android 10, there is no change to private directory reads and writes, and you can still use the `File` set without any permissions. For reading and writing to public directories, you must use the API provided by `MediaStore` or the `SAF` (storage access framework), which means you can no longer use the File set to manipulate public directories at will.

If you set `targetSdkVersion` above `29`,you could try to add below codes into your `AndroidManifest`.Then you could access the `File` as before.

```
<manifest ... >
   <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
       ...
   </application>
</manifest>
```

**Update** (you could try this for public external storage ):

```
var path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("LogFolder").AbsolutePath;
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);


if (!file.Exists())
   {
     file.Mkdirs();
   }
try
   {
     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path + Java.IO.File.Separator + "MyLogFile.txt");
     fw.Write("This is some testing log.");
     fw.Close();
   }
catch (Exception ex)
   {

      string msg = ex.Message;
   }
```

**Update for Android 11**:

add `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your `AndroidManifest`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your activity:

```
  if (Environment.IsExternalStorageManager)
        {
            var path = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory("LogFolder").AbsolutePath;
            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(path);

            if (!file.Exists())
            {
                file.Mkdirs();
            }
            try
            {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(path + Java.IO.File.Separator + "MyLogFile.txt");
                fw.Write("This is some testing log.");
                fw.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
   
        }
        else
        {
         
            StartActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ActionManageAllFilesAccessPermission), 0);
        }
```

Comment: thankyou sir for your reply. It is difficult to understand what you described above. I have added 'requestLegacyExternalStorage' for android 10 support but I need help for android 11. Can you please have a look on above code and suggest a suitable solution with example. Many thanks

Comment: I tried with 'string dirPath  = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath;'  my file and folder get created in package directory but it get deleted when I uninstall the app. . . .

Comment: @user6159419 Yes,`string dirPath = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath;`  it's Internal storage,files will be deleted when the app is uninstalled.You could check above i update when you use external storage.

Comment: Zhu many thanks for your reply and taking interest to solve the issue. You can notice that I have mentioned Android API 30 which is Android-11. Do you think that your code will work for Android-11. Can you please confirm this, because I have doubt about it.

Comment: and also I want the persistant storage/folder/location where files don't get deleted after app uninstallation.

Comment: @user6159419 I update the solution for Android 11 and it works ,you could check it.

Comment: What i need to update to have Environment.IsExternalStorageManager ?? @LeoZhu-MSFT