# Access to the path is denied Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to copy my db file to internal storage root/document. My codes are working good till Android 9 but after it i am getting the error "**System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/FruitsApp/Backup/Fruits.db_2021-06-28 12:20:20" is denied**"
I have try lots of way to copy all are working before Android 9 but after it i am getting above error. I am sharing my all codes. Thanks in advance.

----copy code

```
 Java.IO.File mediaStorageDir = new Java.IO.File(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments) + path);            
            
            if (!mediaStorageDir.Exists())
            {
                var tt = mediaStorageDir.Mkdirs();

                if (mediaStorageDir.Mkdirs() == false)
                {

                    var fail = "failed to create";

                }
            }

       
            var directoryPath = mediaStorageDir.AbsolutePath;


          ////////--this way to create folder is working till andorid 9
           
           //var PathExists = Directory.Exists(directoryPath);

            //if (PathExists ==false)
            //{
            //    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
            //}


            var dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "Fruits.db");


            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(dbPath);

            var dbName = file.Name;

            var fullFileName = string.Concat("/", dbName + "_", Global.CurrentDateTime());

            var newpath = string.Format("{0}{1}", directoryPath, fullFileName);
              
              //////--- First way copy file from source to destination is working tille android 9
              
            //using (FileStream sourceStream = System.IO.File.Open(dbPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            //using (FileStream destinationStream = System.IO.File.Create(newpath))
            //{
            //     sourceStream.CopyToAsync(destinationStream);
            //}

         //////--- 2nd way copy file from source to destination is working tille android 9
            
            byte[] dbFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(dbPath);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(newpath, dbFile);

            
            //////--- 3rd way copy file from source to destination is working tille android 9
            //file.CopyTo(newpath);
```

I have try 3 ways to copy file from source to another all ways are working till android 9 but not working after android 9.

--Android Manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" 
 android:versionName="1.0" package="com.NewWave.FruitApp" android:installLocation="auto">
 <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
 <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" android:label="FruitApp" 
 android:theme="@style/MainTheme"></application>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
 android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
  <!--<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />-->
  </manifest>
```

Comment: Is there anything in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64438193/199364) that helps?

Comment: i am trying  this code

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve this code is working if i want to creat a file and edit this file like txt file but i want to just copy my database file and paste to the document folder

Comment: @user6159419 can u help in this question

Comment: **Which line of code** gives the error message?  And please note this quote in the link I gave: *"For reading and writing to public directories, you must use the API provided by MediaStore or the SAF (storage access framework), which means you can no longer use the File set to manipulate public directories at will."* You probably need to read about those APIs, and change the line of code that fails. Sorry, I'm not familiar with the details.

Answer (score 1):

I have a SQLite database saved in the internal storage of my cellphone, in a folder created folder named SQLite. I had troubles with the permissions and the path. Here's how I solved it:

```
private readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection _conn;  

public LocalContext()
{
    // Create directory for SQLite
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine("/storage/emulated/0/","SQLite"));

    string dbPath = Path.Combine(
    "/storage/emulated/0/SQLite",
    "ventaMovil.db");
    _conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
}
```

Before I called my LocalContext I check if you have writing permissions:

```
private async Task<bool> CheckPermissions()
    {
        var status = await _permissionService.CheckAndRequestPermissionAsync(new Permissions.StorageWrite());
        if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
        {
            await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Error", "You do not have writing permissions", "Okay");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

For the permissions I use Xamarin Essentials:

```
public class PermissionService : IPermissionService
    {
        public async Task<PermissionStatus> CheckAndRequestPermissionAsync<T>(T permission) where T : Permissions.BasePermission
        {
            var status = await permission.CheckStatusAsync();
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                status = await permission.RequestAsync();
            }

            return status;
        }
    }
```

And in the Android Manifest I have these two:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thanks for ans it will help me when user denies any permission, but I solved my question , that have main 2 problems. 1.) after android 10 we need to give all storage permisson whcih can only be given on runtime. 2 ) My database file name was with date and time and the file format was wrong thats why i was getting error.